# How to make text/bg/etc. change colors on loop?

Tags: html, node.js, colors

Let's say i want to make the background go between black and blue. I am using the code

```
    <head>
      <style>
        body {background:skyblue;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      code
    </body>
   </html>
```

and i want for it to change to `{background:black;}` every 2 seconds, then switch back to blue. How do I do that?

Comment: You can do it with strictly CSS only, with help of animations why don't you go check that out. No coding required just simple mark-up.

Comment: For reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_animatable

Comment: And certainly not using node.js

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
      <style>
        body {
          animation: switch 2s linear 0s infinite alternate forwards;
        }
        @keyframes switch {
          from {
            background:skyblue;
          }
          49.9% {
            background:skyblue;
          }
          50.1% {
            background:black;
          }
          to {
            background:black;
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      code
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a way to do it, but it is considered bad practice to have extremely graphical effects like this since it might give people headaches and such if they have to look at screens like this for extended periods of time. Use animations sparingly.